# PHP Script help output yum data just like it would in shell

Tags: php

Hey i have a question here is a printscreen of the issue http://prntscr.com/3zy9kc

I want it to output all data from yum update not just one line
so that is shows full log of the update just like it would if you execute it from the shell
like this

```
    Loading "installonlyn" plugin
    Loading "security" plugin
    Setting up repositories
    Reading repository metadata in from local files
    Installed Packages
    perl.i386                                4:5.8.8-10.el5_0.2     installed
    perl-Archive-Tar.noarch                  1.30-1.fc6             installed
    perl-BSD-Resource.i386                   1.28-1.fc6.1           installed
    perl-Compress-Zlib.i386                  1.42-1.fc6             installed
    perl-DBD-MySQL.i386                      3.0007-1.fc6           installed
    perl-DBI.i386                            1.52-1.fc6             installed
    perl-Digest-HMAC.noarch                  1.01-15                installed
    perl-Digest-SHA1.i386                    2.11-1.2.1             installed
    perl-HTML-Parser.i386                    3.55-1.fc6             installed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just executing `yum update`. If you need to keep log of the command, redirect its output to a file.

```
<?php 

shell_exec("yum update > update.log"); 

?>
```

And then read the file.

PS: Instead of posting a screenshot of the code, post the actual code.

Comment: that doesn't work just gives 1 line of the yum update command    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Comment: Are you reading from update.log? Also how are you reading the log file? programmatically or manually?

Comment: i created the the file using ftp update.log and chmod it to 777

Comment: Don't create the file manually. Run shell_exec("yum update > update.log"); from the program and then open the update.log manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem
By running the script from the browser, it is executed with the permissions of the user of the web server, while **the command needs root permissions**.

Executing the command line script as a normal user, in addition to "Loaded plugins: fastestmirror" also appears the warning that you must have root permissions.

Running in command as root (for example in a cronjob) the command returns the complete list of files to be updated.